# Removing unwanted characters from a URL

Tags: url, naming

Recently I published a website and it's working fine. But when I try to open any linked page its URL looks like this:

```
http://www.englishseekhon.com/English%20Vocabulary%20with%20Hindi%20Meaning.html
```

As you can see, there are a number of `%20` character sequences that I don't want to appear in the URL. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Replace the spaces in that HTML file's name with something else (like underscores).  The `%20` is a URL-encoded space character.

Answer (score 3):

`%20` is the correct [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) form of the space character. If you would like to use a ["Friendly URL"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) format, you'll need to replace the spaces in the name of the resource with a different character.

Hyphens and underscores are generally recommended.

A "dasherized" form of the url would be:

```
http://www.englishseekhon.com/english-vocabulary-with-hindi-meaning.html
```

Comment: And how about the URL of this very page? :-)

Comment: url cannot contain SPACES. and if you dont remove spaces in your coding with other characters I think you can never do what you want. What do you want actually ? show spaces in the URL of page in the address bar ?

Comment: @Meer, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. "url cannot contain SPACES" isn't quite accurate. URLs regularly contain spaces, but they're percent encoded to `%20`, so they don't appear as a space character.

Comment: @Meer - Did you intend to comment on the OP's question rather than on this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the code provided here: http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/c_decode-url.html . The `endcode()` and `decode()` functions will do the trick.

```js
<script> 
    function encode() { 
        var obj = document.getElementById('dencoder'); 
        var unencoded = obj.value; 
        obj.value = encodeURIComponent(unencoded); 
    }

    function decode() { 
        var obj = document.getElementById('dencoder'); 
        var encoded = obj.value; 
        obj.value = decodeURIComponent(encoded.replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Still isn't what the OP was looking for, but someone searching might find this helpful so I didn't recommed deletion when it was flagged ;)

Comment: Yes I agree. He is trying to do something else. Thanks